# AWS Rekognition CLI command works on Bash but not with PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php

I would like to trigger the following command:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx aws rekognition compare-faces --source-image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"xxxx","Name":"test_test.jpg"}}' --target-image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"xxxx","Name":"test_test.jpg"}}' --region ap-northeast-1 --output json
```

It works when I trigger it on bash, but not when I run it in PHP using:

`$result = shell_exec($command);`

It will only return null;

Why is not working on PHP using shell_exec?